Shopware 6. Cart session not correctly managed by Redis
I configured Shopware 6 (6.4) platform for Redis and used 2 different instances of Redis. 1 Instance :
// .env
REDIS_HTTP_CACHE_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_HTTP_CACHE_PORT=6379
REDIS_HTTP_CACHE_DB=0
REDIS_SESSION_CACHE_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_SESSION_CACHE_PORT=6380
REDIS_SESSION_CACHE_DB=0

REDIS_CART_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_CART_PORT=6380
REDIS_CART_DB=1

// config/packages/shopware.yaml:
cart:
   redis_url: 'redis://%env(REDIS_CART_URL)%:%env(REDIS_CART_PORT)%/%env(REDIS_CART_DB)%?persistent=1'
   expire_days: 14
   compress: true

All looks to work fine except that the shopware cart, sometimes, in very random situations seems to cache the "checkout/line-item/add" request . so when i add a product to the cart , the product seems to not appear in the cart. I checked the code and all was perfectly fine. One click may work, second click not ...than 5 clicks works and again it doesn't work.
